# How can I adapt the dimension of the symbol "|" in the displaystyle math mode, without using \left | \right. (or viceversa)?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, overleaf, renewcommand, shortcut

I have to write the symbol for conditional probability "|" but I want to adapt it to the dimension of the sorrounding text in the displaystyle math mode. The only way I know to do it is the following:

```
\left| \cdots \right.
```

I wonder if there is a quicker way that possibly does not employ two commands.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

One may change the size of `|` (vertical bar) directly by prefixing `\big`, `\Big`, `\bigg`, or `\Bigg` to `|` or, if you prefer, `\vert`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\displaystyle 
 \cdots\ 
 \vert \big\vert \Big\vert \bigg\vert \Bigg\vert\ 
 \Bigg| \bigg| \Big| \big| | \
 \cdots$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although you probably want to use `\bigl`/`\bigr` etc., especially with `|` so that the spacing of, e.g., |-10| comes out correctly and not as | - 10|

Comment: @DonHosek - You may well be right. My interpretation of the OP's typographic objective was somewhat different, viz., that they plan to typeset a single vertical bar, not pairs of vertical bars. For sure, I won't go far out on a limb to defend this interpretation. Ideally, the OP would weigh in with some additional information regarding how they plan to use the vertical bars.

Answer (score 0):

Since you seem to want conditional probability, here's some code that can help you.

The idea is the same as `\DeclarePairedDelimiter` in `mathtools`, but slightly improved.

I redefine `\Pr` to give the operator and then examine its optional argument; if it's `*` then autosizing parentheses are used; otherwise the optional argument should contain `big`, `Big`, `bigg` or `Bigg` (no backslash) for fixed size parentheses.

A `|` in the argument produces a suitably sized vertical bar, spaced like a relation symbol.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mleftright}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewCommandCopy{\PrOp}{\Pr}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\Pr}{O{}m}{%
  \PrOp
  \group_begin:
  \char_set_active_eq:nN { `| } \__rosetti_pr_del:
  \char_set_mathcode:nn { `| } { "8000 }
  \rosetti_pr:nn { #1 } { #2 }
  \group_end:
}

\tl_new:N \l__rosetti_pr_del_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \rosetti_pr:nn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #1 }
   {
    {*}{\tl_set:Nn \l__rosetti_pr_del_tl { \;\middle\vert\; }}
    {}{\tl_set:Nn \l__rosetti_pr_del_tl { \mid }}
   }
   {
    \tl_set:Nn \l__rosetti_pr_del_tl { \use:c {#1m}\vert }
   }
  \__rosetti_pr_size:nnn { l } { \mleft } { #1 } (
  #2
  \__rosetti_pr_size:nnn { r } { \mright } { #1 } )
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rosetti_pr_del: { \tl_use:N \l__rosetti_pr_del_tl }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__rosetti_pr_size:nnn
 {
  \str_case:nnF { #3 }
   {
    {*}{#2}
    {}{}
   }
   { \use:c { #3 #1 } }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\Pr{A} \quad \Pr[Big]{A} \quad \Pr[*]{x=\frac{1}{2}} \\
\Pr{A|B} \quad \Pr[Big]{A | B} \quad \Pr[*]{x=\frac{1}{2}|B}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]